# Applying A Class In Multiple Places Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, classname

### Background

I'm working on a project that incorporates a drawer for navigation. When a toggle (`'nav-drawer-toggle'`) is clicked, it opens the drawer and shifts the body over by the drawer's width.

### The Issue

However, I also want to apply the 'navigating' class to my footer (which has a `<footer>` tag) and my header (which has a `<nav>` tag). I've tried adding in `getElementsByTagName('footer')` and `getElementsByTagName('nav')`, but clearly did so improperly. How would I properly get those to work along with the currently-working `getElementById('body')`?

### UPDATE

Now the footer works, but the header is still unchanged. Here's the updated code:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('nav-drawer-toggle');
  var dashboard_body = document.getElementById('body');
  var dashboard_header = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];
  var dashboard_footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];
  checkbox.onchange = function() {
     if(this.checked) {
       dashboard_body.className += 'navigating',
       dashboard_header.className += 'navigating',
       dashboard_footer.className += 'navigating';
     } else {
       dashboard_body.className = '',
       dashboard_header.className = '',
       dashboard_footer.className = '';
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on your html.  I'm guessing you might be having an issue in that `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` both return an `HTMLCollection` and not a single element node.  So if you only have one `<footer>`, you can use `getElementsByTagName('footer')[0]` to get that footer to put the class on.

Comment: Thanks for this, Peter. Oddly enough, the footer works now, but the header still is having issues. I've updated the original question and code snippet accordingly to reflect this.

Comment: No problem.  Before you edited, did you mention that your nav already have a class on it?  If so, when you are adding the `navigating` class to it you are using += with no preceding space, so the class name will now be `origClassNamenavigating` instead of `origClassName navigating`.

Comment: So you'd want `+= ' navigating';`  But just remember when you uncheck the box you will lose the `originalClassName` in addition to `navigating`.  Also I just noticed that you are using commas after some of your statements.  In this case it works ok, but commas mean something specific in javascript so you probably should just use the semi-colons. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 0):

You could likewise give each of the other containers an ID like "footer" and "navbar", and utilize the same code you did above.

```
var dashboard_body = document.getElementById('body');
var dashboard_navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
var dashboard_footer = document.getElementById('footer');
```

The above is pretty repetitive though, but should get you what you need. You could save those objects into an array and later loop through the array, which will save you a few lines of code.

For the sake of completeness (and personal preference) I will say that this is much easier accomplished in jQuery if you're not opposed to using it. If so, it would be as easy as:

```
if (this.checked) {
    $(".your-class-name").addClass("navigating");
} else {
    $(".your-class-name").removeClass("navigating");
}
```

In the above jQuery example, `your-class-name` would be replaced by a CSS class name that you could apply to elements which would be affected by the `navigation` class. Remember that you can use multiple class names separated by spaces (which you may already know), like: `class="my-class cool-class navigating"`

Comment: what would you add to the function part to correspond with the new variables? And in your jQuery example, how would I attach it to the `nav-drawer-toggle` that acts as the toggle? Thanks!